# Merging plotly objects R

Tags: r, regression, plotly, r-plotly

I have two scatterplots and I want to show that the regression lines are different.

In one case, I am considering all the data for 1995-2017. I want to show, that the average is higher for odd years (95,97) than in general.

The data frame for all data is `bayern`, the one for only odd years is `bayern_ohne_wm_em`

That for I create two regression lines with plotly:

```
p1 <- plot_ly(bayern, x = ~Saison, color = I("black")) %>%
  add_markers(y = ~Bayern, text = rownames(bayern), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(Bayern ~ Saison)),
        line = list(color = '#07A4B5'),
        name = "Realität", showlegend = TRUE)

p2 <- plot_ly(bayern_ohne_wm_em, x = ~Saison, color = I("black")) %>%
  add_markers(y = ~Bayern, text = rownames(bayern_ohne_wm_em), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(Bayern ~ Saison)),
            line = list(color = '#000000'),
            name = "Nur Saisons ohne WM/EM zuvor", showlegend = TRUE) 

subplot(p1, p2)
```

[image: This gives me this:]

However, I actually want both lines in one plot.
I would do it by joining both dataframes into `joint2` which I made.
That dataframe looks like this:

```
Saison    Bayern    ohne_WM_EM
2017      81        81
2016      75        NA
...
```

I try that with the following:

```
plot_ly(joint2, x = ~Saison, color = I("black")) %>%
 add_markers(y = ~Bayern, text = rownames(joint2), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
 add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(Bayern ~ Saison)),
           line = list(color = '#07A4B5'),
           name = "Realität", showlegend = TRUE)%>%
add_markers(y = ~ohne_WM_EM, text = rownames(joint2), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
 add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(ohne_WM_EM ~ Saison)),
           line = list(color = '#000000'),
           name = "Nur Saisons ohne WM/EM zuvor", showlegend = TRUE)
```

which gives me this error:

```
Error: Column `y` must be length 1 or 22, not 11
```

Thanks guys!

Edit:

Here some debugging stuff:

```
> dput(bayern)
structure(list(Saison = c(2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995), Bayern = c(82, 88, 79, 90, 91, 
73, 65, 70, 67, 76, 60, 75, 77, 68, 75, 68, 63, 73, 78, 66, 71, 
62)), .Names = c("Saison", "Bayern"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(joint2)
structure(list(Saison = c(2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995), Bayern = c(82, 88, 79, 90, 91, 
73, 65, 70, 67, 76, 60, 75, 77, 68, 75, 68, 63, 73, 78, 66, 71, 
62), ohne_WM_EM = c(NA, 88, NA, 90, NA, 73, NA, 70, NA, 76, NA, 
75, NA, 68, NA, 68, NA, 73, NA, 66, NA, 62)), .Names = c("Saison", 
"Bayern", "ohne_WM_EM"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: We can't run your code without bayern. But as an alternative, you could also convert joint2 from wide to long format and use color for grouping. Also check for the missing values

Comment: How should I export bayern? Screenshot or really the data?
I will try your recommendation

Comment: google dput()!. It does not have to be your full dataset. A subset is enough to run and test your code.

Comment: done it, added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier with `ggplotly()`. You are adding traces with different lengths. Maybe someone else will have a better idea. But it the meantime, you could try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#wide to long
joint2_long <- reshape2::melt(joint2, id.vars=c("Saison"))

a <- ggplot(data=joint2_long, aes(x=Saison, y=value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(a)
```

and it will give you this:

[image]